# Running PostgreSQL Inside a Jail Using FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, postgresql, bsd

I'm using FreeBSD 8.0 and I've setup a jail, pgsql, to act as a database server.  After installing, I've tried to run `initdb` but get the following error:

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/home/pgsql
cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
fgets failure: No such file or directory
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the
same directory as "/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb".
Check your installation.
```

yet `dev/null` exists:

```
root # ls /dev
null
```

and `postgres` is in the same directory:

```
root # find / -name postgres -print
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so `/dev/null` exists, or you have devfs mounted? If you just made a symlink or something, that doesn't work.

Comment: I must have forgotten to remount after a restart.